# Crawl ~50 websites looking for key words (climate) using TF-IDF

Tags: nlp, web-crawler, tf-idf

"Fighting climate change - with words?"

I come from the linguistics + stats side and not from the computer science/programming side of things, so please be patient with me and also thank you!

I'm working on a research project that currently involves expending a lot of time and energy looking at ~ 50 different websites 2-3 times a week to find out about new developments in the energy sector/climate change, so that we don't miss any news (before they get changed or deleted) and want to save and not miss any files of interest.

For now there only is a laughable set-up of bookmarks. But I'd like to make the work easier, if possible, by crawling these websites (every day would be best) looking for changes and in particular by looking for keywords either on (the relevant sections of) the website or within posted documents themselves.

In regards to the documents themselves we are going to employ algorithms (or simple variations) like TF-IDF (Term Frequency - Inverse Document Frequency) and DF-ICF (Document Frequency - Inverse Corpus Frequency) and compare the language used (comparative analysis of corpora) over time and "seasons"  (e.g. political changes).

TLDR: Need help simplifying the gathering of data from ~50 websites looking for keywords by e.g. crawling.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question, although there are several different subjects to address.

1- The crawler: this would be an app which would crawl some pre-defined URLs in search for content. This can be a complex project by it self because you may want to search for specific key-words or bring all the content for that site and filter the result in form of a report containing any news for example...

2- By using an Text Retrieval Model (TRM) you will search for documents containing specific works, which would be your search query. Before you attempt to do what I will suggest you to, I strongly recommend you to watch some videos of [this course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/text-retrieval/supplement/oE9Dw/syllabus), which teaches about the nowadays available TRMs, and their pos and cons.

In a nutshell, I would build a crawler (in Java) and use [BM25](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=188561) which is a very matured TRM to select the documents. Over this search, I would build a report generator, based on the content provided by the mentioned sources. I will get into details of the how-to-do these part because I have no knowledge about climate change, this you will figure out. But concerning the crawler to bring you the results, I will suggest the following set of technologies and APIs ( I build several like this )...

1-Build a maven java project

2-Add lucene dependencies in you pom.xml. I recommend the version 5.5.4.

3-In lucene's search provides several possibilities for TRMs. [This](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) is a 5 min tutotial you can easily implement it in Java. Use BM25 as the similarity mechanism, like this:

```
searcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity(bm25ParameterK, bm25ParameterB));
config.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity(bm25ParameterK, bm25ParameterB));
```

where bm25ParameterK and bm25ParameterB are parameters for the BM25 search. If you want to use the default ( 1.20 and 0.75 ), just set the BM25Similarity like this:

```
searcher.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
config.setSimilarity(new BM25Similarity());
```

There are other TRMs which performs equally well when compared to BM25 like [Pivoted length normalization](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=243206), Query likelihood and PL2, but whose implementations are yet unavailable, as long as I am aware of. I hope I have helped you.

Comment: "I would build a crawler (in Java)" -> why not use an existing one like StormCrawler or Nutch?

Comment: that's why I said "I would...", because there would need too many customizations and instead of trying to adapt one of them, maybe it is easier to build one yourself, although their code may serve as starting point...